# Can I monitor how much time a process spends in iowait in Linux?

Tags: linux

I have an application that has several threads dedicated to doing disk I/O. I would like to be able to monitor how utilized these threads are; that is, how much time they are truly idle waiting for my application to give them data to read/write to disk.

I thought this was straightforward because I could just monitor the proc file system for those threads to watch their user/system time used periodically. However, these values don't seem to include time spent waiting for I/O to complete, which is a significant portion of the time spent by these threads.

Is there a good way to determine how much truly idle (non-iowait) time is spent by a process?

Comment: It's a question more suited for Unix & Linux or Superuser forum, try to move it there. Anyway you can try `top -b -n 1000 -d 0.1 -p <thread PID>`, it will run 1000 times every 0.1 second.